# WebDav Error on saving file: "UPLOAD FAILED: You are required to sign in to upload your changes to this location"

Tags: iis, ms-word, webdav

I have enabled WebDAV on IIS version 6.2 on my server. I want to modify MS Word documents on the server from client machines using WebDAV. MS Office 2016 is installed on client machines and the server. 
so for this purpose, I created a mapped connection to my destination folder on the server:

[image]

Then it asked my credential:

[image]

After entering my login info I could successfully see the contents of my folder.

[image]

But when I want to save my changes on file it throws an error: 
"UPLOAD FAILED: You are required to sign in to upload your changes to this location."

[image]

Does anyone know any solution for this? Am I supposed to sign in somewhere?

Comment: I used to use webDAV a lot for this kind of application, but current versions of Office in both macOS and Windows have problems working directly from webDAV drives now. If you display hidden files, you should be able to see if a temp file gets created on the remote drive. Template files have the first 2 letters of the file name replaced by ~$. If they aren't created, that's probably the source of the error message.

Comment: I checked hidden files on server. When I open  my file in client machine, there is no file starting with ~$ in server. Now what's the soloution for this?

Comment: I doubt there's a fix. But this is not the place to post to get an answer, since this forum is for programming questions. Try answers.microsoft.com or Super User.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm dealing with the same problem. :(

Comment: anyone finds solution for the same I'm facing same issue for Word Versions above 15.0.5....